# Basic Javascript function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, select, button

First off, I am running my code on a Zend server. 
What I am trying to do is have a select drop down, where the user can select different sounds. When they select one, they press the `Quack` button, and then the sound they selected is played. Where I have the code

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Quacked";
```

I need to put code to play audio, but I don't know how. In addition, I cannot figure out the code I need to retrieve the current value of the select dropdown. Where I have

```
var x = document.getElementById("Quack").innerHTML;
```

I need to replace `Quack` with the value of the selected option. How do I do that?

```
<br>
Select: 
<select id = "mySelect">
    <option value="Quack">Quack</option>
    <option value="Chirp"><Chirp</option>
</select>

Press: 
<button type="button" onclick="quack()">Quack!~</button>

<p id = "test"></p>

<script>
    function quack(){
        var x = document.getElementById("Quack").innerHTML;
        if(x=="Quack"){
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Quacked";

        }
        if(x=="Chirp"){
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Chirped";
        }
    }
</script>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of selected index of the drop down like this

```
var e = document.getElementById("Quack");
var x = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Then you can simply play your audio like

```
document.getElementById('IDforYourAudioTag').play();   //HTML
```

An `<audio>` tag looks somewhat like this

```
<audio id="IDforYourAudioTag" src="test.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

[**Good Read**](http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html)